# How can i update the progress in the onProgress Update in using ASYNCTask in mono for Android

Tags: android, for-loop, mono, android-asynctask

I am new in Android Programming.. I'M using Mono for android.. I want to made a progressdialog that show the progress when i'm importing data. I use Asynctask.. Anyone can help how to make my progress dialog show the progress. Or else any suggestion of what can be other possible way in making this.

```
public class importData : AsyncTask
{

private ProgressDialog _progressDialog;
WebReference.Service1 service = new WebReference.Service1();
private Context _context;




public importData(Context context)

{

_context = context;



}

protected override void OnPreExecute()

{
// i make a horizontal progressdialog, i want to see the progress while importing

base.OnPreExecute();
_progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(_context) { Indeterminate = false };
_progressDialog.SetMessage("Please wait...");
 _progressDialog.SetProgressStyle(ProgressDialogStyle.Horizontal);
_progressDialog.Max = 806;
_progressDialog.Progress = 0;
_progressDialog.Show();

}

protected override Java.Lang.Object DoInBackground(params Java.Lang.Object[] @params)

{
try
{
//My background Code in Importing Data
return true;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
//When has an error return false
return false;
}


}

protected void OnProgressUpdate()
{
base.OnProgressUpdate();
//What i'm going to put in this part

}

protected override void OnPostExecute(Java.Lang.Object result)

{
base.OnPostExecute(result);
_progressDialog.Hide();
_progressDialog.Dismiss();
bool dd = (bool)result;
if (dd)
{


//Toast.MakeText(this, "Importing data completed", ToastLength.Short).Show();
Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(_context);
AlertDialog ad = builder.Create();
ad.SetTitle("Info");
ad.SetIcon(Android.Resource.Drawable.IcDialogInfo);
ad.SetMessage("Importing deals completed");
ad.SetButton("OK", (s, e) => { });
ad.Show();
}
else {

Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(_context);
AlertDialog ad = builder.Create();
ad.SetTitle("Error");
ad.SetIcon(Android.Resource.Drawable.IcDialogAlert);
ad.SetMessage("Failed");
ad.SetButton("OK", (s, e) => { });
ad.Show();
}
}


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Modified you code below. Hope it helps. Or give you an idea. In DoinBackground Loop your progressdialog and pass it in onprogressupdate using this.publishProgress ..

```
public class importData : AsyncTask
{

private ProgressDialog _progressDialog;
WebReference.Service1 service = new WebReference.Service1();
private Context _context;




public importData(Context context)

{

_context = context;



}

protected override void OnPreExecute()

{
// i make a horizontal progressdialog, i want to see the progress while importing

base.OnPreExecute();
_progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(_context) { Indeterminate = false };
_progressDialog.SetMessage("Please wait...");
 _progressDialog.SetProgressStyle(ProgressDialogStyle.Horizontal);
_progressDialog.Max = 806;
_progressDialog.Progress = 0;
_progressDialog.Show();

}

protected override Java.Lang.Object DoInBackground(params Java.Lang.Object[] @params)

{

try
{
for(int i=0; i<_progressDialog.Max; i++) {
    this.PublishProgress(i);
}
//My background Code in Importing Data
return true;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
//When has an error return false
return false;
}


}



protected override void OnProgressUpdate(params Java.Lang.Object[] values)
{
base.OnProgressUpdate();
//increment the progress of your progrssdialog
_progressDialog.IncrementProgressBy(1);

}

protected override void OnPostExecute(Java.Lang.Object result)

{
base.OnPostExecute(result);
_progressDialog.Hide();
_progressDialog.Dismiss();
bool dd = (bool)result;
if (dd)
{


//Toast.MakeText(this, "Importing data completed", ToastLength.Short).Show();
Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(_context);
AlertDialog ad = builder.Create();
ad.SetTitle("Info");
ad.SetIcon(Android.Resource.Drawable.IcDialogInfo);
ad.SetMessage("Importing deals completed");
ad.SetButton("OK", (s, e) => { });
ad.Show();
}
else {

Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(_context);
AlertDialog ad = builder.Create();
ad.SetTitle("Error");
ad.SetIcon(Android.Resource.Drawable.IcDialogAlert);
ad.SetMessage("Failed");
ad.SetButton("OK", (s, e) => { });
ad.Show();
}
}


}
```